# Finding the expected value of a bivariate gaussian distribution

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, bivariate-distributions

Suppose that $(A,B)$ have a standard Gaussian distribution on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

How do I find the expected value for $\mathbb{E}[max(3.9A+B,A+3.9B)]$?

I know that A and B follow the standard normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $1$. But how do I get the expected value from this?

Thank you!

Comment: $ \mathbb{E}[max(3.9A+B,A+3.9B)] = \mathbb{E}[ (3.9A+B) | A \gt B] \cdot P(A \gt B) + \mathbb{E}[ (A+3.9B) | B \gt A] \cdot P(B \gt A)$

Comment: @MathLover Thank you for your comment, however, I am still a bit lost how I can find the expected values. If you could explain more it would be really great. Thanks!

Comment: @MathLover and also may I ask how you got the conditional probabilities?